# Javascript String to int conversion

Tags: javascript, string, int, type-conversion

I have the following JS immbedded in a page:

```
var round = Math.round;
var id = $(this).attr("id");

var len = id.length;
var indexPos = len -1; // index of the number so that we can split this up and used it as a title

var pasType = id.substring(0, indexPos); // adult, child or infant
var ind = round(id.substring(indexPos)); // converts the string index to an integer
var number = (id.substring(indexPos) + 1); // creates the number that will go in the title
window.alert(number);
```

`id` will be something like adult0, and I need to take that string and split it into adult and 0 - this part works fine.

The problem comes in when I try to increment the 0. As you can see I use Math.round to convert it to an integer, and then add 1 to it - I expect 0 to be 1 after this. However, it doesn't seem to be converting it to integer, because I get `01`, not `1`. When testing this with adult1 the alert I get is `11`.

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1133770/1073118) question for reference, and have also tried `var number += id.substring(indexPos);`, which breaks the JS (`unexpected identifier '+='`)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You have already converted a number - just use it: `number = ind + 1`.

Comment: What if you get past `adult9`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `parseInt()` function parses a `string` and returns an `integer`,10 is the Radix or Base
[**[DOC]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
var number = parseInt(id.substring(indexPos) , 10 ) + 1;
```

Comment: FYI: *always* pass the radix parameter to parseInt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 17):

**Convert by `Number Class`:-**

Eg:

```
var n = Number("103");
console.log(n+1)
```

**Output:** 104

**Note:-** `Number` is class. When we pass string, then constructor of `Number class` will convert it.

Comment: But if the string has extra chars in it then it will be NaN.

Comment: Working with a string of floating numbers, this worked for me. Simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 12):

This is to do with JavaScript's `+` in operator - if a number and a string are "added" up, the number is converted into a string:

```
0 + 1; //1
'0' + 1; // '01'
```

To solve this, use the `+` unary operator, or use `parseInt()`:

```
+'0' + 1; // 1
parseInt('0', 10) + 1; // 1
```

The unary `+` operator converts it into a number (however if it's a decimal it will retain the decimal places), and `parseInt()` is self-explanatory (converts into number, ignoring decimal places).

The second argument is necessary for `parseInt()` to use the correct base when leading 0s are placed:

```
parseInt('010'); // 8 in older browsers, 10 in newer browsers
parseInt('010', 10); // always 10 no matter what
```

There's also `parseFloat()` if you need to convert decimals in strings to their numeric value - `+` can do that too but it behaves slightly differently: that's another story though.

Answer (score 10):

JS will think that the 0 is a string, which it actually is, to convert it to a int, use the: parseInt() function, like:

```
var numberAsInt = parseInt(number, 10);  
// Second arg is radix, 10 is decimal.
```

If the number is not possible to convert to a int, it will return NaN, so I would recommend a check for that too in code used in production or at least if you are not 100% sure of the input.

Answer (score 5):

Although `parseInt` is the official function to do this, you can achieve the same with this code:

```
number*1
```

The advantage is that you save some characters, which might save bandwidth if your code has to lots of such conversations.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `number*1` is not the same as `parseInt` for all inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Use parseInt():

```
var number = (parseInt(id.substring(indexPos)) + 1);` // creates the number that will go in the title
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure id.substring(indexPos) is a number, you can do it like so:

```
var number = Number(id.substring(indexPos)) + 1;
```

Otherwise I suggest checking if the Number function evaluates correctly.